# CSV record with a comma in it being inferred as separate fields

Tags: csv, rust

So I am using Rust's CSV module to read a CSV file, but I see an issue that I have a workaround to, but it's just not sitting well with me because it's either just a hack or I don't know any better.

Issue: In the records themselves, some values have a comma (and obviously they're expected to have), and my code breaks at that, saying `CSV error: record 3 (line: 4, byte: 73): found record with 4 fields, but the previous record has 3 fields`. This is correct, the previous record is `1970,  17, "Bloody Mama"` and the next one - the one it's breaking at - is `1970,  73, "Hi, Mom!"`. As you can see, it has a comma in the third field. I have been able to resolve it using the `flexible` flag (`.flexible(true)`), which essentially is telling the Reader whether the number of fields in records will be changed in the future, meaning it is inferring the field in question as two separate fields. I just wanted to know if that can be avoided somehow or if that is what I'd have to live with. Because I wish the reader not to wrongly infer my value as two different values.

Here's the code for it:

```
    let mut rdr: csv::Reader<fs::File> = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
                                    .quoting(false)
                                    .trim(csv::Trim::All)
                                    .flexible(true) // With this enabled, it works/prints fine.
                                    .from_path(file)?;
```

Comment: Your csv data is malformed. You can't put spaces around your comma separators. Fix your data and the parser will work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, that's understandable - that you cannot have spaces around the separators. But do you know if the `delimiter()` flag can help with that? It doesn't like spaces, looks like. I have tried  `delimiter(b',  ')`, but that doesn't work. So do you suggest to remove all the spaces first between the commas and then feed it to the ReaderBuilder?

Comment: Reading the example in the documentation for `.trim`, it seem that the trimming is done only after parsing the field, where the quote `"` is expected at the very start of the field. So it does indeed seem like the `csv` crate will not do exactly what you want.

Comment: You can't set multi byte delimiters. Your data is formatted badly. Either you need to fix it at the source, or run some kind of processing step with your own parser to fix it. FYI, I'm the author of the csv crate.

Comment: Take a look at the spec for CSV files.
Available [here](https://csv-spec.org/)
Look at paragraph 9.  It says that a space between the comma and the double quote is incorrect.  It also says that the parser should issue a warning, which apparently, it does not in your case.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I knew it, but then there is always a possibility that you're the 5th impostor. BUT what you're saying does indeed make sense. I will give it a shot, thanks though.

Comment: @WalterMitty - Thanks for pointing it out. I think I will perhaps preprocess the CSV file first and then proceed.

Comment: @WalterMitty Most CSV parsers do not adhere to the "spec" for CSV files because it's far too strict to be useful in real world scenarios. Python's CSV parser does the same thing. `list(csv.reader(io.StringIO('1970, 17, "Hi, Mom!"')))` yields `[['1970', ' 17', ' "Hi', ' Mom!"']]`. Like Python's parser, Rust's csv crate is designed to always prefer *some* parse over an error. When `flexible` is disabled, the only possible error is an I/O error.

Comment: @BurntSushi5  agreed.  The spec even says that it is a guideline and not a spec.  I tried Import-Csv in Powershell and got a wrong parse.  Rust may be the same.

Answer (score -2):

If there are some values with quotes `"` in your data, why are you setting the `quoting` parameter to false?
According to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.ReaderBuilder.html#method.quoting):

> quoting
> Enable or disable quoting.
> This is enabled by default, but it
> may be disabled. When disabled, quotes are not treated specially.

So I think

```
.quoting(false)
```

should be set to `true`

```
.quoting(true)
```

Either that, or just leave it out because true/enabled is the default.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but ...

1. It hasn't helped with an issue I had previously reported, and
2. It doesn't help here either.